# How do I clear a .zshrc file without opening the Terminal? (Have an eval infinite loop)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zshrc

I created an infinite loop in my **~/.zshrc** file and now when ever I open my terminal it is unuseable.

How do I clear a my .zshrc file with out using the terminal?

Infinite loop is essentially:

```
eval $(foo)

foo() {
    open -a Terminal -n
}
```

Mac 11.4

Answer (score 2):

Ok.

Open Finder

(Command , Shift, H) lets you see all files, not just applications. Can edit it from there via text editor.